# How do I add a alternative input to "exit" or "continue"?

Tags: java

I have done this:

```
public class Socialsec {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a Social Security number in the format DDD-DD-DDDD, where D is a digit: ");
        String userInput = in.nextLine().trim();

        String socSec = "(\\d\\d\\d)-(\\d\\d)-(\\d\\d\\d\\d)";
        Pattern ssNum = Pattern.compile(socSec);
        Matcher matcher = ssNum.matcher(userInput);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(userInput + " is a valid social security number.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(userInput + " is not a valid social security number.");
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to add the possibility to the user, either the user enters "continue" or "exit" to exit. I dont know how to add that to the statement, is it with a "while" statement? Because I want the option on both the true answer and the false answer. the "option" should always be there after displaying true or false.

SO example: "Enter "Continue" to continue and "Exit" to quit: "

Comment: You will definitely need a loop (`for` or `while`) to repeat the code of interest until _some condition_ says otherwise. In your case, the condition is entering `exit` as your input. This can be supplemented with a `break;` statement on an infinite `while(true)` loop, or by making it the condition your loop continues off of.

Comment: Dont really know how to do this any guide you can link?

Comment: The [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) from Oracle cover all of this in pretty fine detail (by the second "chapter" no less), for instance their guide on the [`while` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest code would be something like this:

```java
public class SocialSecurityValidator {

    public static boolean isSocialSecurity(String value){
        String socSec = "(\\d\\d\\d)-(\\d\\d)-(\\d\\d\\d\\d)";
        Pattern ssNum = Pattern.compile(socSec);
        Matcher matcher = ssNum.matcher(value);
        return matcher.matches();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean doExit = false;
        while (!doExit){
            System.out.println("Enter a Social Security number in the format DDD-DD-DDDD, where D is a digit: ");
            String input = in.nextLine().trim();
            if (input.contains("exit")){
                doExit = true;
            } else if (isSocialSecurity(input)) {
                System.out.println(input + " is a valid social security number.");
            } else {
                System.out.println(input + " is not a valid social security number.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I moved your social security regular expression into a method that does only that.

Then, I created a boolean variable to keep the loop alive until the user types `exit`.

If you have any question about the code let me know.

Comment: wow really nice! But what I was looking for was to be able to see the option "Exit" and "continue" then users should type "Continue" or "Exit", if user type "Continue" it will ask for social security again. On "Exit" the program should end. So basically the program should ask if I want to continue or exit, depending what input the user puts in, it continues alternative quits the program. Hope I explained enough. Thanks for the help!